# SVG Filter animation won't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-filters

I ran into an issue where safari doesn't want to apply svg filters to a child element that is animated. It seems like an you can animated the parent of an element with a filter applied (second example), but you can't apply the filter to the parent of an animated element (the first example.

Is this just a limitation of safari? Are there any workarounds that still allow the container to apply the filter? Thank you!

For context, I'm working with a 3D cube and as you can see applying the filter to the parent allows for a more 3D effect, and in my case a consistent filter applied to all the sides of the cube which are all separate divs

```css
@keyframes rotate-animation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes filter-animation {
  from {
    filter: url("#turbulence-1");
  }
  to {
    filter: url("#turbulence-2");
  }
}

.container {
  animation: filter-animation 0.25s linear infinite alternate;
  width: fit-content;
}

.square {
  animation: rotate-animation 10s linear infinite;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg display="none">
        <defs>
            <filter id="turbulence-1">
                <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="2" data-filterId="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" scale="25" />
            </filter>

            <filter id="turbulence-2">
                <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.03" numOctaves="2" data-filterId="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" scale="25" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
@keyframes rotate-animation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes filter-animation {
  from {
    filter: url("#turbulence-1");
  }
  to {
    filter: url("#turbulence-2");
  }
}

.container {
  animation: rotate-animation 10s linear infinite;
  width: fit-content;
}

.square {
  animation: filter-animation 0.25s linear infinite alternate;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg display="none">
        <defs>
            <filter id="turbulence-1">
                <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="2" data-filterId="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" scale="25" />
            </filter>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#

            <filter id="turbulence-2">
                <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.03" numOctaves="2" data-filterId="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" scale="25" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you check that your snippets show the 3D effect on some browsers (which?). I am not seeing any 3dness on Edge/Chrome or Firefox on Windows 10. (And I had to remove the svg's display="none" to see anything on FF).